# Connection exception in java jdbc

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

This is one of constructors of class. New object create new record in database. When I create this object "by hand" in source code, everything is fine. But when I put declaration of creation into actionlistener of a button, compiler returns sql exception.

```
public Pacjent()
    {
        try
        {
            Connection conn = DataBase.Connect();
            Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
            String addRecord = "INSERT INTO records VALUES (12365, 'Bond', 'James', 'M', '12.41.1953r', 'Londyn', 'none');";
            stat.executeUpdate(addRecord);        
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    

}
```

Exception that I get is

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:714)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.createStatement(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:230)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.createStatement(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:191)
>     at klasySilnika.Pacjent.(Pacjent.java:61)     at
>   klasyInterfejsu.NowaKarta$1.actionPerformed(NowaKarta.java:155)   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

and this is actionlistener:

```
saveButton.addActionListener
        (
            new ActionListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
                {
                    Pacjent nowy = new Pacjent();
                }
            }
        );
```

Database.Connect method:

```
public class DataBase 
{
    public static Connection Connect()
    {
        return CONNECTION;
    }        

    private static Connection CONNECTION = CreateConnection();

    private static Connection CreateConnection() 
    {
        try 
        {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

            Properties props = new Properties();
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("D:\\projekty\\Arch\\src\\klasySilnika\\bazadanych.properties");
            props.load(in);
            in.close();

            String drivers = props.getProperty("jdbc.drivers");
            if(drivers != null) System.setProperty("jdbc.drivers", drivers);
            String url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
            String username = props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
            String password = props.getProperty("jdbc.password");

            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,password);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("NO JDBC driver");
        return null;
    }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Where is properties file?");
            return null;
        } 
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("error: adress, user, password?");
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
           // ...   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `Database.Connect()` method do? Also, I would recommend you use *Prepared Statements*.

Comment: It returns connection object. Its based on properties file, returned object is ready to work. Check out my edit.

Comment: Hope you're not closing connection in `finally` block. Finally, gets called no matter what, even if there is a `return` before it.

Comment: before this actionPerformed, is there any other database activity ?

Comment: In class where is actionPerformed there is none. Exception appears when actionPerformed is used in program. There is no exception before using it, but before using it there is database activity. Program read records from database and put it on screen.

Comment: You seem to be closing the connection at some point.

Comment: check your whole code base and see where all you are using DataSource.Connect() and then see if there is somewhere connection.close() statement

Comment: Yes. I've found it, connection was closed after program read database and put it on screen - so before i used action listener. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe the connection instance is closed in other place,because your connection is static,the whole application only one instance of connection,so you can change the connection to muti-instance or manage by datasource eg:c3p0,dhcp

Answer (score -1):

```
public Pacjent()
{
    try
    {
        Connection conn = DataBase.**CreateConnection**();
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        String addRecord = "INSERT INTO records VALUES (12365, 'Bond', 'James', 'M', '12.41.1953r', 'Londyn', 'none');";
        stat.executeUpdate(addRecord);        
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

You can Change your Method to   CreateConnection

Comment: Best Way to Open and close Connection url : http://www.javasolution.in/search/label/Connection